# Why does Debian package Scalar::Util in libperl and perl-base?

Tags: debian, perl

I was just checking something out on Debian, when I use `apt-file` to search for `Scalar/Util.pm` a CORE Perl module I see three results,

```
$ apt-file search Scalar/Util.pm
libperl5.34: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.34.0/Scalar/Util.pm
libscalar-list-utils-perl: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.34/Scalar/Util.pm
perl-base: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base/Scalar/Util.pm
```

This makes 2/3 sense, because

- `libscalar-list-utils-perl` represents the package on CPAN.
- `libperl5.34` and `perl-base` represents the package in Perl.

What doesn't make sense though is why these two package the same version of the same module,

- `libperl5.34`
- `perl-base`

Currently `perl-base` is described as,

> This package provides a Perl interpreter and the small subset of the standard run-time library required to perform basic tasks. For a full Perl installation, install "perl" (and its dependencies, "perl-modules-5.34" and "perl-doc").

And `libperl5.34` is described as,

> This package contains the shared Perl library, used by applications which embed a Perl interpreter. It also contains the architecture-dependent parts of the standard library (and depends on perl-modules-5.34 which contains the architecture-independent parts).

Is there a technical reason why `perl-base` and `libperl5.34` package the same module? And why would `perl` depend on both of them?

Comment: Have you examined them to make sure that they actually are the same file?

Comment: @NasirRiley the only difference is the one `perl-base` has the docs cut out. If you cut the docs out the one packaged by `perl-base` they hash the same. But why would that matter? Why would `perl` need one copy with the docs cut out, and the other with them not cut out?

Comment: Then they aren't the same file. If you want to get to the bottom of it, then it's probably better to ask the actual developers.

Comment: lol. k, I changed "file" to "module"

Answer (score 1):

`perl-base` provides the `perl` binary and a minimal set of modules, with no ancillary binaries and no documentation. As pointed out in the comments, the modules have their documentation stripped out.

`perl` provides a complete Perl environment, with all the expected binaries and documentation. It depends on `perl-base` because that’s where the `perl` binary itself is, and on `libperl5.34` because that’s where the architecture-dependent modules are.

`perl-base` is an essential package, installed on all Debian-based systems; that’s why it’s kept as small as possible (within reason). `perl` isn’t essential, and it’s conceivable to have a Debian-based system without it.